# Java String matching : € symbol is â¬

Tags: java, string, string-matching

I am searching for the presence of certain characters in a Java String like this ...

```
                                         // LineBreak ^   {      }      \        [     ~      ]      |     €
private static final String CHARACTERS = "\u000c\u005e\u007b\u007d\\\u005c\\\u005B\u007e\\\u005D\u007c\u20ac";

public static boolean doesCharacterExist(String input) {
    return input.matches('[' + CHARACTERS + "]*");
}
```

However, a `€` isn't being detected. When I debug through the code, the `€` is represented by `â¬` in the String. What is the easiest way to detect it (preferably without changing the way my code currently works)?

**Edit -** the exisitng JSP has an include at the top of it ...

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/commonElements/include.jsp" %>
```

and that include has the following UTF-8 encoding line ...

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="utf-8" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %>
```

Comment: € vs. â¬ sounds like a character encoding issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the complete `String` using `String#matches`:

```
return input.matches(".*[" + CHARACTERS + "].*");
```

UTF-8 header for JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"  
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>  
<%  
    System.out.println("Character encoding : "+request.getCharacterEncoding());  
    System.out.println("Character encoding : "+response.getCharacterEncoding());  
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");  
%>
```

Comment: Hi Reimeus. This broke a lot of my unit tests. I'm not a regex expert, so i may have misunderstood, but does your fix compare the entire String? The input String could be a series of characters, not just one character. So for example, "Hello€World" should be a match but "Hello World" should not.

Comment: Mmm. Actually looking further, maybe Ive not quite understood what your change has done. Some unit tests are broken, some are not.

Comment: Yes it does, currently your `String#matches` expression does not match the "Hello" & "World" characters beside the € symbol. That's the reason for the `.*`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I didn't explain myself properly. The String I provided above is a simplified version of my code. The actual string is much longer, and includes the usual letters of the alphabet, so "Hello€World" are all characters that are allowed to be in the string.

Comment: But "Hello™World", for example, should NOT be a match. I want to ensure that € is an allowed character.

Comment: You would still need the fix above though. I've added a UTF8 encoding header for a JSP page above

Comment: The first part of your JSP example is already in the code (I've added this info to my question). The second part was not already in my code, but I've added it, but it doesn't stop the String from being â¬

Answer (score 0):

`€` is only represented as one character.  If you encode the string it may appear as two or three characters depending on the encoding.  I

t sounds like you are trying to scan a string which was read using the wrong encoding so it is not creating the string you started with. i.e. what should be euro, appears as two characters incorrectly.

Comment: The String was inputted from a GUI. The front end page was written (by someone else) as a jsp. Does the encoding need to be in the jsp? This is new territory for me.

Comment: Your encoding must be the same end to end. I suggest UTF-8. If not characters can be mangled or lost.

Comment: How and where do I do the encoding? In Java in my method above? or in the jsp? Or somewhere else?

Comment: The string you get is incorrect so you have to ensure it is right before you get it in your code.